# Scipy installation using pip has been killed on Google cloud instance

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, pip, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am new to google clouud and I'm trying to install scipy on my google cloud instance.

When I'm executing the following command on google cloud shell in order to install scipy but the process of installation has been killed.

Command for installation

```
pip install scipy
```

During the installation I'm getting the following message.

```
Collecting scipy
Downloading scipy-0.19.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (45.0MB)
99% |████████████████████████████████| 45.0MB 46.8MB/s eta 0:00:01Killed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Try the following command:

```
pip --no-cache-dir install scipy
```

Depending on your Google Cloud VM settings installing `scipy` in a limited memory environment can cause problems. It seems like `pip` is trying to read in the complete file into memory before caching it. By running the command stated above you ask `pip` to avoid caching which should be the solution for the process being killed at 99%.

Comment: I would like to add that the Digital Ocean droplets of the minimum config have this restriction and this works lovely there.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The cloud shell is not intended to be used for doing heavy computation and has a lot of [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations).

I would recommend you create a [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) virtual machine and then use the shell to SSH in it.